# Putting .SVG images into tkinter Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cairo, rsvg

I have been trying to put the image from https://betacssjs.chesscomfiles.com/bundles/web/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.f387b3f2.svg into a Tkinter frame. I found from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583035/can-you-display-an-image-inside-of-a-python-program-without-using-pygame) that it is possible with the help from rsvg and cairo.

I was using python 3.6 on Windows 10. I got rsvg from [here](https://github.com/GNOME/librsvg) and cairo from [here](https://github.com/vishnubob/cairo) and then extracted the folders to the 'C:\Users...\site_packages' folder. They import fine but I cannot figure out how to use them. I tried using the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
main=tk.Tk()
frame=tk.Frame(main)
def svgPhotoImage(self,file_path_name):
        from PIL import Image,ImageTk
        import rsvg,cairo 
        svg = rsvg.Handle(file=file_path_name)
        width, height = svg.get_dimension_data()[:2]
            surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, int(width), int(height))
            context = cairo.Context(surface)
            #context.set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_SUBPIXEL)
            svg.render_cairo(context)
            tk_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage('RGBA')
            image=Image.frombuffer('RGBA',(width,height),surface.get_data(),'raw','BGRA',0,1)
            tk_image.paste(image)
            return(tk_image)
    tk_image=self.svgPhotoImage(filename)
    frame.configure(image=tk_image)
```

and

```
#rsvg.py
import os
try:
    import rsvg
    WINDOWS=False
except ImportError:
    print"Warning, could not import 'rsvg'"
    if os.name == 'nt':
        print "Detected windows, creating rsvg."
        #some workarounds for windows

        from ctypes import *

        l=CDLL('librsvg-2-2.dll')
        g=CDLL('libgobject-2.0-0.dll')
        g.g_type_init()

        class rsvgHandle():
            class RsvgDimensionData(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("width", c_int),
                            ("height", c_int),
                            ("em",c_double),
                            ("ex",c_double)]

            class PycairoContext(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("PyObject_HEAD", c_byte * object.__basicsize__),
                            ("ctx", c_void_p),
                            ("base", c_void_p)]

            def __init__(self, path):
                self.path = path
                error = ''
                self.handle = l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(self.path,error)


            def get_dimension_data(self):
                svgDim = self.RsvgDimensionData()
                l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle,byref(svgDim))
                return (svgDim.width,svgDim.height)

            def render_cairo(self, ctx):
                ctx.save()
                z = self.PycairoContext.from_address(id(ctx))
                l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo(self.handle, z.ctx)
                ctx.restore()



        class rsvgClass():
            def Handle(self,file):
                return rsvgHandle(file)

        rsvg = rsvgClass()).
h = rsvg.Handle("box.svg")
s = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 100, 100)
ctx = cairo.Context(s)
h.render_cairo(ctx)
```

After trying those scripts, I kept getting the error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'rsvg' has no attribute 'Handle'
```

I am sure I did something wrong in the process but after hours of searching still could not figure out how to get it to work. I also tried installing pycairo (via pip) but got the error message

```
ERROR: Command "'c:\...\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\...\\pip-install-peqhj3x1\\pycairo\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\...\Temp\pip-record-jfozfbuc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\...\pip-install-peqhj3x1\pycairo\
```

I have no clue as to what to do now

> EDIT: I was finally able to obtain pycairo from
>   https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and now  have it working.
>   I finally got rsvg to not give me the error message above by referring
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414829/attributeerror-module-rsvg-has-no-attribute-handle)
>   and got the nessary DLL files from
>   [here](https://github.com/jmcb/python-rsvg-dependencies). **Cairo is
>   working fine but RSVG is creating a blank screen.** I tried another
>   7-liner
>   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463524/python-svg-converter-creates-empty-file)
>   and get the output of a blank file instead of a converted one.
>   Evidently RSVG is not working and I think it is an installation issue
>   (eg. incorrect .dll's). Help?

If am trying to use cairo and rsvg because they take up little space and are really fast; wand or some other library is not an option. I just want to be able to put an SVG file into a tkinter frame. If anyone knows how install rsvg properly, I'd appreciate knowing.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Hi, the code I mainly used is present in the lase and 2nd last links.

Comment: code in links work but your code not. So if you show code then we can search differences.

Comment: I added the code to the question. I think the errors are from how I installed cairo and rsvg rather than the code itself.

Comment: I think that you should be able to use PIL.Image and PIL.ImageTk to do so

Comment: @БогданОпир I can't figure out how to load a svg from the hard drive or internet with PIL. If you have any insights, I'd love to know.

Comment: Take a look at https://pypi.org/project/svglib/. In its example the svg is converted into png which allowes you to use PIL

Comment: Did you try renaming `rsvg.py` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to convert SVGs with Python 3 and PyCairo on Windows, but without rsvg. Rsvg still won't cooperate, but apparently it is still possible to load SVGs without it.

The installation process is not very straightforward, but hey, it works!

**Instructions:**

Note that these instructions are Windows-specific. On Linux, one can simply install pycairo via pip and use PyGObject's rsvg.

1. Download the pycairo .whl file for your Windows installation from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).
2. Install the downloaded file via pip: `pip install /path/to/your/pycairo/whl.whl` If that doesn't work, try using a different file from the above link. It may take a few tries.
3. Run `pip install tinycss cssselect2 defusedxml`. This will install the dependacies for the next step.
4. Go to https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG. Download and extract the `cairosvg` folder to your site packages folder, enabling your code to import it.
5. Go to the `cairosvg` folder and open the file `surface.py`.
6. Look for the line that says `import cairocffi as cairo` and replace it with `import cairo`

That should be enough to use PyCairo on Windows without a C++ compiler. Unfortionately, this still doesn't fix the rsvg issues (instead it replaces rsvg), but at least it works.

**Here are some examples of how to use it:**

To convert an SVG to a PNG:

```
import cairosvg
cairosvg.svg2png(url="example.svg", write_to="output.png")
```

To put an SVG into a Tkinter window without downloading the output:

```
import cairosvg
import io
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

main=tk.Tk()

image_data = cairosvg.svg2png(url="example.svg")
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

button=tk.Label(main, image=tk_image)
button.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
main.mainloop()
```

Since it still uses Cairo, this solution is very quick, and has few dependencies.

Hopefully this answer will be useful for anyone reading this in the future!

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to do it using svglib:

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF, renderPM

drawing = svg2rlg("safari-pinned-tab.f387b3f2.svg")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "temp.png", fmt="PNG")


from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()


from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = Image.open('temp.png')
pimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
size = img.size


frame = Canvas(tk, width=size[0], height=size[1])
frame.pack()
frame.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=pimg)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! The question was about rsvg, though. Any insights? Also, if it is possible to use svglib/reportlab without downloading the shape? Is it possible to somehow skip reportlab altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to **j_4321** for his answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829808/870802

I am just shining a slightly different light here in case it helps anyone.

From what I have been able to find, **tksvg** is the easiest and simplest way to visualise a SVG graphic in **tkinter 8.6**. I have been able to do the below in IDLE:

```
python -m pip install tksvg    ---> this is not in IDLE actually, but in cmd!

import tkinter as tk
import tksvg

window = tk.Tk()

d = '''<svg width="0" height="0"><path d="M17.2 26.6l1.4 2.9 3.2.5-2.2 2.3.6 3.2-2.9-1.5-2.9 1.5.6-3.2-2.3-2.3 3.2-.5zM44.8 3.8l2 .3-1.4 1.4.3 2-1.8-.9-1.8.9.3-2L41 4.1l2-.3.9-1.8zM8.9 10l.9 1.8 2 .3-1.4 1.4.3 2-1.8-.9-1.8.9.3-2L6 12.1l2-.3zm37.6 17l.647 1.424 1.553.258-1.165 1.165.26 1.553-1.424-.776-1.295.647.26-1.553-1.165-1.165 1.553-.259zM29.191 1C24.481 2.216 21 6.512 21 11.626c0 6.058 4.887 10.97 10.915 10.97 3.79 0 7.128-1.941 9.085-4.888-.87.224-1.783.344-2.724.344-6.028 0-10.915-4.912-10.915-10.97 0-2.25.674-4.341 1.83-6.082z" fill="#7694b4" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>'''

# if you have a SVG file on disk, use the file parameter:
# svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage( file = 'path/to/file' )

# if you have SVG code from somewhere - in my case I scraped it from a website - use the data parameter:
svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage( data = d )

# You can also resize the image, but using only one of the three available parameters:
# svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage( data = d, scale = 0.5 )
# svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage( data = d, scaletowidth = 200 )
svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage( data = d, scaletoheight = 200 )

tk.Label( image = svg_image ).pack()
```

The final result is:

[image]

If you keep the SVG source code handy you can always resize the image by generating a new one.

Versioning: Windows 7x64, Python 3.8.10, tkinter 8.6.9.0, tksvg 0.7.4

Comment: This is great, but incomplete. Last line should read `tk.Label( window, ...`, then add another line like `window.mainloop()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
from pylunasvg import Document
import numpy as np
from urllib import request
from PIL import Image

contents = request.urlopen("https://betacssjs.chesscomfiles.com/bundles/web/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.f387b3f2.svg").read()

document = Document.loadFromData(contents)
bitmap = document.renderToBitmap()

svgArray = np.array(bitmap, copy=False)
img = Image.fromarray(svgArray)

# Insert tkinter code here
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the bindings for the library, here is the github link: [pylunasvg](https://github.com/erentknn/pylunasvg) and link to the original library written in c++: [lunasvg](https://github.com/sammycage/lunasvg/tree/master)