# AttributeError: module 'rsvg' has no attribute 'Handle'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, rsvg

I have been trying to put a SVG image in tkinter. I have installed cairo and rsvg but when running my script, get the error: `AttributeError: module 'rsvg' has no attribute 'Handle'`
This is my script:

```
#some code to give rsvg.render_cairo(ctx) ability
#on windows.
import os
try:
    import rsvg
    WINDOWS=False
except ImportError:
    print("Warning, could not import 'rsvg'")
    if os.name == 'nt':
        print("Detected windows, creating rsvg.")
        #some workarounds for windows

        from ctypes import *

        l=CDLL('librsvg-2-2.dll')
        g=CDLL('libgobject-2.0-0.dll')
        g.g_type_init()

        class rsvgHandle():
            class RsvgDimensionData(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("width", c_int),
                            ("height", c_int),
                            ("em",c_double),
                            ("ex",c_double)]

            class PycairoContext(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("PyObject_HEAD", c_byte * object.__basicsize__),
                            ("ctx", c_void_p),
                            ("base", c_void_p)]

            def __init__(self, path):
                self.path = path
                error = ''
                self.handle = l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(self.path,error)


            def get_dimension_data(self):
                svgDim = self.RsvgDimensionData()
                l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle,byref(svgDim))
                return (svgDim.width,svgDim.height)

            def render_cairo(self, ctx):
                ctx.save()
                z = self.PycairoContext.from_address(id(ctx))
                l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo(self.handle, z.ctx)
                ctx.restore()



        class rsvgClass():
            def Handle(self,file):
                return rsvgHandle(file)

        rsvg = rsvgClass()
h = rsvg.Handle("index.svg")
s = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 100, 100)
ctx = cairo.Context(s)
h.render_cairo(ctx)
```

I am using windows with python 3x.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the whole error message. Otherwise we cannot see where the error occurs.

Comment: @figbeam The full error is:  ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\whoever\filepy", line 5, in <module>
    import rsvg
  File "C:\Users\whoever\rsvg.py", line 55, in <module>
    h = rsvg.Handle("index.svg")
AttributeError: module 'rsvg' has no attribute 'Handle'```

Comment: It is because your filename is `rsvg.py` and `import rsvg` will import current file and it does not have `Handle` function or class.

Comment: Thanks! I  got it to work.

Comment: @Andoo can you please share how you solved the problem?

Comment: @shantanurahut I simply renamed the fine from rsvg.py to somethingelse.py. Unfortionately, rsvg still isn't cooperating, though. It gives me a blank screen (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943631/putting-svg-images-into-tkinter-frame)

Comment: @Andoo somebody should solve this rsvg problem on windows. I am gonna get fired over this. -_-

Comment: @shantanurahut I feel your pain. I'll check through my old code and see if I can figure out a way to get it to work (I've already spent months on this, though). PyGObject does have an rsvg package, by the way, but to install it on Windows will you need a C compiler. It does work though. It may also be possible to extract PyGObject's rsvg from the rest of the PyGObject package, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @shantanurahut I just came up with a solution (sort of)!!! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943631/putting-svg-images-into-tkinter-frame/65298522#65298522.

Comment: @shantanurahut No problem! Glad I could be helpful. It is funny that in 2020 it is this hard to convert an SVG image.