# How to open SVG files in tkinter?

Tags: python, svg, tkinter

I want to be able to open SVG files in tkinter. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60951861/14056244) I'm using right now converts the SVG into a PNG before showing it in tkinter, but since I want to be to resize it without losing quality, I need a better answer.

Comment: By “open” do you mean “display”, or just open it like a text file to read its contents?

Comment: Tkinter cannot handle SVG, so if you don't want to lose quality, you will need to convert again your original SVG each time you resize it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I do mean display.

Comment: @j_4321 Are there any scalable graphic formats that tkinter can handle as scalable?

Comment: Tkinter has no support for svg

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, are there any scalable graphic formats that tkinter can handle as scalable?

Comment: @DUO No, tkinter cannot not handle any kind of vector graphics format

Comment: No, tkinter has no support for scalable graphic formats.

Comment: But some kind of svg support is going to be added to next version of Tk (8.7): https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/507.md, otherwise you can try to use the library [tksvg](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tksvg) but you will need to use it through the tcl interpreter

Comment: @j_4321 Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some basic svg support will be part of tk 8.7 (https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/507.md).

But to add svg support to tk 8.6, it is necessary to install an extra package like [tksvg](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tksvg).  So, first install tksvg, following the instructions from [here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tksvg). Then you can create a `PhotoImage` from a svg file but you need to load tksvg in the tcl interpreter. I wrote a quick python wrapper for tksvg:

```
import tkinter as tk

class SvgImage(tk.PhotoImage):
    """Widget which can display images in PGM, PPM, GIF, PNG format."""
    _tksvg_loaded = False
    _svg_options = ['scale', 'scaletowidth', 'scaletoheight']

    def __init__(self, name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw):
        # load tksvg
        if not SvgImage._tksvg_loaded:
            if master is None:
                master = tk._default_root
                if not master:
                    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
            master.tk.eval('package require tksvg')
            SvgImage._tksvg_loaded = True
        # remove specific svg options from keywords
        svgkw = {opt: kw.pop(opt, None) for opt in self._svg_options}
        tk.PhotoImage.__init__(self, name, cnf, master, **kw)
        # pass svg options
        self.configure(**svgkw)

    def configure(self, **kw):
        svgkw = {opt: kw.pop(opt) for opt in self._svg_options if opt in kw}
        # non svg options
        if kw:
            tk.PhotoImage.configure(self, **kw)
        # svg options
        options = ()
        for k, v in svgkw.items():
            if v is not None:
                options = options + ('-'+k, str(v))
        self.tk.eval('%s configure -format {svg %s}' % (self.name, ' '.join(options)))
```

So `SvgImage` is like a `PhotoImage` but it has the additional options (only one of them can be specified since they are three different way of specifying the image size):

- `scale`
- `scaletowidth`: width in pixel
- `scaletoheight`: height in pixel

Here is an example:

```
root = tk.Tk()

def rescale():
    global scale
    scale += 0.5
    img.configure(scale=scale)

scale = 0.5
img = SvgImage(master=root, file='/path/to/file.svg', scale=scale)
tk.Button(root, image=img, command=rescale).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no way of doing this without losing quality resolutions, but if svglib was not good enough maybe cairo can do it better. Try the code bellow. It has the advantage that you don't really need the image as a png file, but since PIL does not handle svg you have to convert it anyway:

```
from io import BytesIO
import cairosvg
from PIL import Image

out = BytesIO()
cairosvg.svg2png(url='path/to/svg', write_to=out)
image = Image.open(out)
```

Comment: So, you're saying tkinter can't handle SVG?

Comment: Yes. It only handles with specific image object. You normally use PIL to create such objects but PIL don't handle SVG