# How to install cairo and rsvg for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cairo, rsvg

I understand that Stackoverflow is for help with code, but I figured I'd ask anyways.

I found from the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583035/can-you-display-an-image-inside-of-a-python-program-without-using-pygame) that it is possible to put a .svg file into a tkinter window, but after days of searching, I still **can't find any place where I could install cairo and rsvg from.**

I am currently using Windows 10 with python 3.6.

> EDIT:
>
> I have found out how to install cairo and rsvg. Cairo is working but
> rsvg is not. I have managed to put SVGs in Tkinter with cairo and not rsvg, though.  For
> anyone curious about this, you may want to check post out:
> [Putting .SVG images into tkinter Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943631/putting-svg-images-into-tkinter-frame#answer-65298522).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: Ok, so pip won't work for installing pycairo. Found that out.
>   And the other options haven't worked for me either. I am about to be
>   away from my computer, but I'll give you some of the things I found.
>   [This](http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2012/03/installing-pygtk-pypango-and-pycairo-on.html)
>   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704407/how-do-you-install-pycairo-cairo-for-python-on-windows)
>   and
>   [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131876/pycairo-installation-on-windows)
>
> Sorry I couldn't be more help. Hope you figure it out!

First, use `pip install pycairo`

Unfortunately, rsvg is unavailable for windows, but cairographics.org have a simple wrapper.

Save the following as rsvg.py in the same folder as your script:

```
#some code to give rsvg.render_cairo(ctx) ability
#on windows.
import os
try:
    import rsvg
    WINDOWS=False
except ImportError:
    print"Warning, could not import 'rsvg'"
    if os.name == 'nt':
        print "Detected windows, creating rsvg."
        #some workarounds for windows

        from ctypes import *

        l=CDLL('librsvg-2-2.dll')
        g=CDLL('libgobject-2.0-0.dll')
        g.g_type_init()

        class rsvgHandle():
            class RsvgDimensionData(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("width", c_int),
                            ("height", c_int),
                            ("em",c_double),
                            ("ex",c_double)]

            class PycairoContext(Structure):
                _fields_ = [("PyObject_HEAD", c_byte * object.__basicsize__),
                            ("ctx", c_void_p),
                            ("base", c_void_p)]

            def __init__(self, path):
                self.path = path
                error = ''
                self.handle = l.rsvg_handle_new_from_file(self.path,error)


            def get_dimension_data(self):
                svgDim = self.RsvgDimensionData()
                l.rsvg_handle_get_dimensions(self.handle,byref(svgDim))
                return (svgDim.width,svgDim.height)

            def render_cairo(self, ctx):
                ctx.save()
                z = self.PycairoContext.from_address(id(ctx))
                l.rsvg_handle_render_cairo(self.handle, z.ctx)
                ctx.restore()



        class rsvgClass():
            def Handle(self,file):
                return rsvgHandle(file)
```

In your script, do `from rsvg import *` and when you need to use it, run:

```
rC = rsvgClass()
h = rC.Handle("YOUR-FILE-HERE.svg")
s = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 100, 100)
ctx = cairo.Context(s)
h.render_cairo(ctx)
```

Comment: you cant name the file rsvg.py, due to the fact that it `try`s to `import` the actual rsvg module that would be installed on any other person's machine except windows... naming the file rsvg.py and then `try`ing to import rsvg means that you would be `try`ing to import your rsvg.py file and not the library that would be installed on other machines. So the class would never be created. Learned that the hard way.

Comment: I am scouring the internet for way to long now to get this to work. this code does not work for me because my pc cant find the .dll, and it seams the internet has no windows dlls for libsrvg. how did you get this to work?